# Weird issue in for textbox render

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am have very weird issue in IE. I have attached a screen with this.
My textbox is not showing 100% text, I have applied all CSS tricks like height, height on div, height on textbox, padding, margin but nothing works.

Any suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: It actually was visible, but now gone. Anyway, first is padding (`padding:0;`), second is font size (`font-size: 0.8em;`). Try to play with this params until text become visible.

Comment: please update your code on jsfiddle or give some code snippets or else live link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give line height as per your text field. Each time you need to keep line height same and text field height like below

```
input[type='text'] { 
    font:normal 15px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#A7A7A7;
    border:1px solid #DFDFDF;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    padding:5px 12px;
    height:26px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    width:93%;
    margin-bottom:11px;
    outline:none;
    }
```

Comment: working with height but we client dont want height upto 26px when i decrease it upto 18px facing the same issue... really getting mad with this

Comment: when you decrease the height upto 18px you have to also decrease the line height upto 18px. Demo link here http://jsfiddle.net/BvX9h/2/